# how to group the layouttemplate in listview

Tags: asp.net, listview

I know the way to group the item . but how to group the layouttemplate each 8 databound items ?

here is the code

```
<ul class="slides">
                <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="MyListView" OnItemDataBound="MyListView_ItemDataBound" GroupItemCount="2" >
                    <LayoutTemplate>
                        <li>
                            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceHolder" />
                        </li>
                    </LayoutTemplate>
                    <GroupTemplate>
                        <div class="gourptpl">
                            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server"  ID="itemPlaceHolder"/>
                        </div>
                    </GroupTemplate>
                    <GroupSeparatorTemplate>
                        <div class="sper"></div>
                    </GroupSeparatorTemplate>  
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%-- The item template is used to render each of the rows of the DataTable that has been binded to the ListView control. --%>
                        <div class="ft-item">
                            <span class="ft-image">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="ButtonText" />
                                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
                                </asp:LinkButton>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
                 </ul>
```

All i want is to repeat the GroupTemplate each 2 items and the LayoutTemplate each 8 items .
Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I helped myself . nest another listivew in the itemtemplate of the listview above . Actually i wanna customize the listview class but dun know how .